# How to drag a formula in google sheet?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

[image]

I want to divide all the numbers from A63 to A65 with the number in cell A61, and put the results in cells from B63 to B65

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use in B63:

```
=INDEX(A63:A65/A61)
```

if you still want to drag it use:

```
=A63/A$61
```

Comment: whats the significance of $ before 61?

Comment: it freezes the row 61 from changing in the next row after you drag it